# Is using the computer for MFA safe?

Tags: authentication, passwords, account-security, multi-factor, one-time-password

Recently, I discovered that MFA apps just calculate that codes based on a private key and the time clock, so it's easy to use tools like [gnu pass](https://www.passwordstore.org/) to replace those apps with your computer.

But what are the securities drawbacks when we do that? The point of MFA is to ensure that an attack needs not only the username and password but access to some physical device, right? Can computers with MFA programs meet this requirement? What are the situations in which computer use can be a security flaw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can computers with MFA programs meet this requirement?

They meet this requirement

- as long as they can keep the secret for the MFA sufficiently private to the physical device
- and can make sufficiently sure that only the authorized person can execute the MFA calculating program with the secret key on the device

> What are the situations in which computer use can be a security flaw?

If an attacker is able to get the secret and use it on some other device, the secret cannot no longer be considered a factor only associated with the specific user, since it can also be used by others. This is also true if an attacker is able to remotely control the device and get the result of the MFA computation when they need it, i.e. even without knowing the underlying secret key.

Thus, if the device is compromised the factor should be considered compromised too.

Comment: Useful note: the reason that TOTP 2FA is usually done on smartphones (Google Authenticator etc.) is in part because the Android and iOS security model makes it difficult to access an app's private data from outside that app. This is typically much more difficult than on a PC, where the flat filesystem does little to limit access to another app's data which contains the 2FA secret.